# How to connection uploaded file to get_ontology() function?

Tags: r, shiny, bioinformatics

I want to use Shiny to demo my R analysis process.

Because my original file is .obo format. 
So I need to use get_ontology function(ontologyIndex package) to read it in R.

But when I use Shiny's fileinput() function to input the file, it can't connect to get_ontology() to read it.

The error message shows
[image]

ui.r

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
navbarPage( title = 'Patent Analysis System',

#Table1----------------------------------------------------           
            tabPanel("Upload Patent File", fluidPage(
              # App title ----
              titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

               # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
                sidebarLayout(
                # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
                sidebarPanel(

                  # Input: Select a file ----
                  fileInput("patent_file", "Choose Patent File",
                            multiple = TRUE,
                            accept = c("text/csv",
                                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                       "csv")),

                  # Input: Select a Ontology file ----
                  fileInput("ontology_file", "Choose Ontology File",
                            multiple = TRUE,
                            accept = c(".obo")),

                  # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
                  radioButtons("file_disp", "File Display",
                               choices = c(Patent = "patent",
                                           Ontology = "ontology"),
                               selected = "patent")
                  ),

                 # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
                 mainPanel(
                  # Output: Data file ----
                  tableOutput("contents")
                  )
                )
              )
              ),
  #Table2----------------------------------------------------           
  tabPanel('Preprocess',fluidPage(
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Preprocess Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      conditionalPanel(
        'input.dataset === "diamonds"',
        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                           names(diamonds), selected = names(diamonds))
      )
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("ex1")
    )
  )
)
)
)
```

server.r

```
function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$patent_file will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

     inFile <- input$patent_file
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    req(input$patent_file)
    patent_df <- read.csv(input$patent_file$datapath)

    if (is.null(patent_df))
      return(NULL)

    req(input$ontology_file)
    ontology_df <- read.csv(input$ontology_file$datapath)

    if(input$file_disp == "patent") {
      return(patent_df)
    }
    else if (input$file_disp == "ontology") {
      return(ontology_df)
    }
})

#---------------------------
  library(ontologyIndex)
  library(ontologyPlot)

  # display 10 rows initially
  output$ex1 <- renderDataTable({
  ontology_get <- get_ontology(input$ontology_file, propagate_relationships = "is_a")

  #Plot ontology
  plot_ontology <- onto_plot(ontology, terms=ontology$id, frequencies = NULL,
            edge_attributes = list(color = "#000000", lty = "solid"), 
            fontsize = 35,
            width =1,
            fixedsize = "true",
            shape = "circle")  
  }
 )
}
```

Comment: Why are using ` ontology_df <- read.csv(input$ontology_file$datapath)` to read the file, instead you should be using `get_ontology`. Also, loading libraries inside `server` is not a good idea. Try loading it outside the `server`

Comment: get_ontology(input$ontology_file$datapath, ...)